# How to add a ScrollBar to a GroupBox

Tags: c#, scrollbar, groupbox

Is there any method to add a scroll bar to a group box? My code scenario is: I have many groupboxes on a form. All the groupboxes will appear in the same place and also the height and width is fixed. I'm setting groupboxes visible true/false according to a condition.

Some groupboxes ecxeed the width and height, so I want to put this all in scrollbar. Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: Is this for windows forms or WPF ?

Answer (score 2):

If its an Windows application then you need to add a panel to Group box and set a property "AutoScroll"=true.

Answer (score 0):

place a groupbox on your form then add this code

```
int btnPos = 1;
Panel pnl = new Panel();
pnl.AutoScroll = true;
pnl.Top = 15;
pnl.Left = 2;
pnl.Width = groupBox1.Width - 8;
for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
{
    Button _btn = new Button();
    _btn.Text = "lbl";
    _btn.Top = btnPos;
    btnPos += 23;
    pnl.Controls.Add(_btn);
}
groupBox1.Controls.Add(pnl);
```